# Lock and unlock screen - iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

Would it be possible to lock a device screen and unlock it again? The reason I would want to do this is we have a kiosk type app and we would like to turn of the screen between certain times.

I would think a type of push notification would be needed?

Answer (score 1):

Once iPad is locked you're not going to be able to unlock it programmatically, even through a push notification. Assuming these devices are always plugged in you may be better off turning off the idleTimer (which I'm assuming you already have) then invoke some sort of screen save or idle screen that displays during those hours. That way your app never allows the iPad to lock natively and you can control when clients do & don't see the content.

That brings up a design question, though... what happens if someone is present when the idle screen is up? Should you override or keep it on the idle screen? Just thinking out loud.

Comment: Thanks, ok, so thats out of the question to lock the device. Well the store is closed on those times, its just a way of preserving some energy and saving the screens. But if its not possible its not possible :-)

Comment: Out of pure curiosity why don't you do this: kill the idleTimer in the app until it's time for the store to close, that way the app allows the iPad to go to sleep and preserve energy overnight. When the associates come back in the morning they unlock the iPad, fire up the app and when the app fires up again have it check the current time and if it's within a certain threshold disable the idleTimer again <repeat>